# Binding Command of Button in AppBar does not work

Tags: c#, binding, winrt-xaml

Why does the Command in the following example not execute?

I have a named Page with an AppBar and a Button in it:

```
   <Page
    x:Class="App13.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    x:Name="myPage"
    >
    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <AppBar>
           <Button Content="OK" Command="{Binding OkCommand, ElementName=myPage}" />
        </AppBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
</Page>
```

The Command "OkCommand" is defined in the code-behind like this (using MVVM light framework):

```
public RelayCommand OkCommand
{
    get
    {
        return m_OkCommand
            ?? (m_OkCommand = new RelayCommand(
                                  async () =>
                                  {
                                      await new MessageDialog("OkCommand").ShowAsync();
                                  }));
    }
}
```

There are no binding-errors nor any other hints in the output-window that give me an idea why this does not work. 
(Aside: if the button is placed outside the AppBar, everything works fine)

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

There should be no reason for the command binding not working for a button in `AppBar` if it works for a button elsewhere on the page.

I suspect the problem is related to how `DataContext` is set. You should have it set at the page level instead of lower in the control tree. All the other buttons are inside the top content control of the page while the `AppBar` is outside of it causing the binding not to work if `DataContext` is set at the top content control or below.

You can try it with the following  working example:

`MainPage.xaml`:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
    x:Class="App16.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App16"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:common="using:App16.Common"
    x:Name="MyPageName"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel x:Name="MainGrid" Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button Content="Ok" Command="{Binding OkCommand}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <AppBar x:Name="bottomAppBar" Padding="10,10,10,10"  >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource SkipBackAppBarButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding OkCommand}" >
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </AppBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
</common:LayoutAwarePage>
```

`ViewModel.cs`:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private RelayCommand _okCommand;
    public RelayCommand OkCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _okCommand
                ?? (_okCommand = new RelayCommand(
                                      async _ =>
                                      {
                                          await new MessageDialog("OkCommand").ShowAsync();
                                      }));
        }
    }
}
```

`MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : LayoutAwarePage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you example. Using an explicit ViewModel works fine (and gives me at least some Workaround).
However, I should have been more specific with my question: what does not work is binding to a named element via '{Binding Path=OkCommand, ElementName pageRoot}' if the OkCommand is defined in code-behind. 
I have veryfied this once again. The binding to 'pageRoot' works if defined in the page-XAML but does not work, if the binding is used within the AppBar-XAML. Strange. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @CEvenSharper As it seems `AppBar` elements don't see the rest of the page hence `ElementName` binding doesn't work. Since you're having your `Command` in code behind, you could use `Click` event handler directly instead of `Command` unless you also need `CanExecute` for disabling it. Or you could create a separate `ViewModel` which I generally find a better idea not a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is for Windows RT/8, however I ran into this same problem with Universal Apps (UWP) and I found the solution using the new {x:Bind}. Note, by default x:Bind will map to OneTime instead of {Binding} where it was OneWay.

I found this pattern while watching one of the MSDN Windows 10 Developer videos on the new XAML Bind.

Modify YourPage.cs

```
public sealed partial class YourPage : Page
{
    public ViewModels.YourPageViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public YourPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        if (DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled) return;

        this.DataContextChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            ViewModel = DataContext as ViewModels.YourPageViewModel;
        };
    }
}
```

Modify YourPageViewModel.cs

```
public class YourPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ICommand newFunctionCommand;
    public ICommand NewFunctionCommand { get { return newFunctionCommand; } }

    public YourPageViewModel()
    {
        if (DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled) return;

        if (newFunctionCommand == null)
            newFunctionCommand = new ICommand(new Action(NewFunction));
    }

    protected void NewFunction()
    {

    }
}
```

Modify YourPage.xaml

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:YourViewModel x:Name="YourVM" />
</Page.DataContext>

<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar ClosedDisplayMode="Compact">
        <AppBarButton x:Name="AddAppBarButton" IsCompact="True"
                      Label="New" Icon="Add"
                      Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.NewFunctionCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```