# How to set AppBar DataContext

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, mvvm-light

As far as I can tell it's as if nothing is hooked up.  The text boxes do not grab the value or set the value in the VM and the button command does not get hit upon click.

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <AppBar>
        <AppBar.DataContext>
            <Binding Path="AppBar" Source="{StaticResource Locator}"/>
        </AppBar.DataContext>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Margin="0,0,20,0" TextAlignment="Center" Height="25" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding IPAddress}"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Margin="0,0,20,0" TextAlignment="Center" Height="25" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Port}"></TextBox>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}">Save</Button>
        </Grid>
    </AppBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
<Page.DataContext>
    <Binding Path="Main" Source="{StaticResource Locator}"/>        
</Page.DataContext>
```

Comment: what framework are you using with Locator?

Comment: For those of you having this problem in Windows 10, please see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365407/binding-command-of-button-in-appbar-does-not-work/33045346#33045346).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging the eventhandler AppBar.DataContextChanged? The app bar's datacontext is originally set to the correct value, but it goes bad a moment later when data context changed is executed again with the new datacontext as null. So I suggest adding a switch to revert to the good datacontext if a null value shows up.

XAML

```
<AppBar DataContextChanged="AppBar_DataContextChanged" ... />
```

C#

```
    private object _dataContext;
    private void AppBar_DataContextChanged(FrameworkElement sender, DataContextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.NewValue != null)
        {
            if (_dataContext == null)
            {
                _dataContext = args.NewValue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (_dataContext != null)
            {
                sender.DataContext = _dataContext;
            }
        }
    }
```

If you want the textbox to update the viewmodel, binding mode must be TwoWay.

```
<TextBox Margin="0,0,20,0" TextAlignment="Center" Height="25" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding IPAddress, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
<TextBox Margin="0,0,20,0" TextAlignment="Center" Height="25" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Port, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong Windows 8 Store Apps doesn't supporting binding in Application Bar.

More on the discussion here,
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/a27c9c88-82c5-43fb-9fd9-6ae36dc39af6/appbar-databinding-does-not-work-because-datacontext-is-not-available?forum=winappswithcsharp